# Print out json objects in Angular2 depending on how the json object looks like

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to print out the region, crimePerCapita, and the population from the following JSON object. Depending on if I want the data for a specific region or the entire country I get the two following JSON objects below.

I have a string which can either be "whole-country" or a specific region. I was thinking about doing an ng-If on this string, checking if it's equal to "whole-country" so I print the values out for the whole country. If the string is not equal to this value I would like to print only one region out.

The reason to why I want to split it up in two different views is because the JSON objects don't look the same if I look for only one region compared to more than one region.

```
//JSON
//If we fetch a specific region, it looks like this:
{"region":"blekinge","crimePerCapita":"0.0064","population":156253.0}
// If we want to retrieve the entire country (not a specific region like in the case above), we get this: 
[{"region":"stockholm","population":2231439.0},{"region":"uppsala","population":354164.0}]

//Typescript
items: any[] = [];

onClickStatistics(region: string): void {
    this.region = region;
    this.httpService.getStatistic(this.region)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          const myArray = [];
          for (let key in data) {
            myArray.push(data);
            console.log(data);
          }
          this.items = myArray;
          }
      );
  }

<!-- HTML -->
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li>{{item.region}}</li>
    <li>{{item.population}}</li>
    <li>{{item.crimePerCapita}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about putting selected region in array so that array then contains one object, while looping if there is a crimePerCapita attribute angular will display it, if not then there is nothing to display

Comment: You mean adding a method (called onSelect let's say), that creates an array with only one object (the selected region object), and then looping over that?

Comment: Also, the only reason to why the json from the whole country does not have a crimePerCapita attribute is because the server is currently not returning that. It should though.

Comment: so what actually do you want to do with region? print it in <li> element?

Comment: region is a variable that is taken from a dropdown list that the user selects. After they select this region it should call a GET from the server with the URL: localhost/feed/region
Example: localhost/feed/blekinge

This GET request gives back the following json that I posted above and depending on if the URL is /whole-country or a specific region I get the two different answers. So what I want to do is to be able to print them both out in a list, however because they look differently in the json this is not possible with the same HTML code.

Comment: it is possible. if you push first object to array of other response objects angular will skip undefined elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126528/discussion-between-dev-in-progress-and-kemkoi).